# Get all classes and interfaces that are used in another class with Roslyn?

Tags: roslyn

the question is this: I have some source file:

```
namespace TestSln
{
    public class AAA
    {
        private DDD x;

        private void func(CCC z)
        {
            BBB b = new BBB();
            b.z();
        }
    }
}
```

The output I'm looking for is this: 
The class AAA uses: "DDD, CCC, BBB"

How can I achieve this with Roslyn?

P.S. I want to be able to read the entire solution, and search in all the projects for classes that are referenced in this source file.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own [`SyntaxWalker`](http://go/scrcast/NDgzODU3Nzg2NzMyNTQ0MHxkZWY3Y2ZjMS05Zg), and call `GetSymbol()` on your `SemanticModel` for every node in `Visit()`.   You can simply add each symbol to a `Set<ISymbol>` to collect a full list.